# how to run more than one programe by the RUN (windows)

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I need run more than one programe by the Run in windows
your can show it if you click 
the Windows logo key+R.

i need 2 programe ex: cmd and regedit

thanks :)

Comment: `cmd /k start regedit` will leave a command window & regedit running

Comment: no i need more than it i need par example run a reg and powershell and my programe by run in one time

Comment: can i run cmd in hide (i want cmd not show) ??

Comment: I suggest searching google before asking for code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, `cmd /c start "" write&start "" notepad&start "" iexplore` under <kbd>WinLogo</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> dialog runs

- `write.exe` - *WordPad* document editor
- `notepad.exe` - *plain text* file editor
- `iexplore.exe` - *Microsoft Internet Explorer* browser

[image: WinLogo+R]

**Edit: disadvantage**. In fact, above method

- needs to use unhandy notation with `cmd /c`, multiple `start ""`, multiple `&`
- and flashes command line window shortly.

However, anyone can write a primitive program which would simulate that <kbd>WinLogo</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> dialog (e.g. in `C#` or even in such simple language as `VBSript`) with above handicap eliminated. 
For instance, [Guidelines for Keyboard User Interface Design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971323.aspx#atg_keyboardshortcuts_selecting_access_keys) gives some hints, e.g. for designing shortcut keys as well as list of (commonly used)

- System-Wide Shortcut Keys,
- System-Wide Accessibility Options and Tools Shortcut Keys (incomplete),
- General Shortcut Keys for Applications,
- Navigation and Window Controls Shortcut Keys,
- Menu Controls Shortcut Keys,
- Edit Box Shortcut Keys,
- Dialog Box and Common Controls Shortcut Keys,
- Windows Explorer Shortcut Keys,
- Microsoft Office XP Shortcut Keys.

**Further resources** (`cmd` related reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`&` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: i do not want show a cmd (black box)